# break an long line in an algorithm

Tags: equations, line-breaking, amsmath, algorithms, algorithm2e

I have a long line in an algorithm and want to break it into two lines. For similar case in `equations`, `split` can be used. How do I do this within an algorithm?

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage[boxed,vlined,linesnumbered,noresetcount]{algorithm2e}
\begin{document}
\begin{algorithm}[tp]
out := foo(x$\rightarrow$child[which]
,$\langle$1,0,0,old$\rangle$
,$\langle$0,0,0,new$\rangle$)\;
\end{algorithm}
\end{document}
```

[image: output]

Comment: Try `\linebreak` at the place you want to break the line.

Comment: the problem with linebreak is, it does not indent the next line. In my case that might be misleading. If the second line is indented inside, then it would be easy to understand that it is part of the previous line

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Setting the breakable portion in a `\parbox` of sufficient width allows you to break it at will as well as properly align the content:

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{mathtools}
\usepackage[boxed,vlined,linesnumbered,noresetcount]{algorithm2e}
\begin{document}
\begin{algorithm}[tp]
  \texttt{out} $\vcentcolon=$ \textsc{foo}($\texttt{x} \rightarrow \texttt{child[which]}$, $\langle 1,0,0,\texttt{old} \rangle$, $\langle 0,0,0,\texttt{new} \rangle$\;
  \texttt{out} $\vcentcolon=$ \textsc{foo}(\parbox[t]{.6\linewidth}{%
    $\texttt{x} \rightarrow \texttt{child[which]}$, \\
    $\langle 1,0,0,\texttt{old} \rangle$, \\
    $\langle 0,0,0,\texttt{new} \rangle$)\;}
\end{algorithm}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Or maybe `varwidth` in order to avoid enlarging the total width of the construction.

Answer (score 5):

Something like this, with adjustable indentation. The solution defines a new command called `\myindent` constituted with `\newline` and `\makebox{#1}{}`, taking one argument for length.

[image]

Code

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage[boxed,vlined,linesnumbered,noresetcount]{algorithm2e}
\newcommand{\myindent}[1]{
\newline\makebox[#1cm]{}
}
\begin{document}
\begin{algorithm}[tp]
out := foo(x$\rightarrow$child[which]
\myindent{0.3},$\langle$1,0,0,old$\rangle$
\myindent{0.3},$\langle$0,0,0,new$\rangle$)\;
\end{algorithm}
\end{document}
```

Comment: I figured out another way to do it using `\Indp` and `\Indm`. It looked good. But is that a right way to do it?

Comment: A problem can be tackled in many ways. As long as it is in the realm of LaTeX, sure.

Answer (score 3):

You can define a new command `\WRP` like that:

```
\newcommand{\WRP}{\par\qquad\(\hookrightarrow\)\enspace}
...
\begin{document}
...
\begin{algorithm}[H]
\begin{algorithmic}[1]
...
\STATE This line\WRP needs to be wrapped
```

**Syntax:** `\newcommand{\name}[args]{definition}`

**Note:** Make sure the command isn't already defined.

**Result:**

[image: Line wrap in algorithm]

Answer (score 0):

In LaTeX, there are several ways to break a long line in an algorithm. One of the simplest ways is to use the double backslash (**\\**) at the end of the line. However, sometimes this may not work well, especially when the line is inside some intended structures such as a **for** loop or an **if** block.

In this case, using the **\quad** command can be helpful. The \quad command adds a horizontal space equivalent to the width of the character "q" in the current font. You can use \quad multiple times to create a suitable space.

Here's an example of using double \quad to break a long line inside a for and if block in an Overleaf algorithm:

```
\begin{algorithm}
\caption{Example algorithm}
\begin{algorithmic}[1]
\For{obj in objects}
    \If{criteria}
        \State $x = x_1 + x_2 + x_3 +$\\
        \quad \quad $x_4 + x_5 + x_6 + x_7 + x_8$
    \EndIf
\EndFor
\end{algorithmic}
\end{algorithm}
```

Comment: In the text, you say expliciltly, forward double slash; in the code, there's only a double backslash.

Comment: You are right, a double backslash is correct, I will edit my post. Thanks for your comment.