# Erroneous placement of `then` in a broken line of the algorithm

Tags: line-breaking, algorithmicx

I've used the proposed strategy [here](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/194846/break-an-long-line-in-an-algorithm) (`\parbox`) to break the long condition of my `\If` block:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{mathptmx}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage{fdsymbol}
\usepackage{algorithm}
\usepackage{algorithmicx,algpseudocode}
\usepackage[top=2cm, left = 2cm, right = 2cm, bottom = 2cm]{geometry}

\algnewcommand\algorithmicforeach{\textbf{for each}}
\algdef{S}[FOR]{ForEach}[1]{\algorithmicforeach\ #1\ \algorithmicdo}

\algnewcommand\algorithmicinput{\textbf{Input:}}
\algnewcommand\INPUT{\item[\algorithmicinput]}

\algnewcommand\algorithmicoutput{\textbf{Output:}}
\algnewcommand\OUTPUT{\item[\algorithmicoutput]}

\let\oldReturn\Return
\renewcommand{\Return}{\State\oldReturn}

\makeatletter
\newcommand{\algrule}[1][.2pt]{\par\vskip.5\baselineskip\hrule height #1\par\vskip.5\baselineskip}
\makeatother

\begin{document}

        \begin{algorithm}[tbp]
        \caption{ttt}
        \begin{algorithmic}[1] 
            \INPUT $x$
            \OUTPUT $y$
            \algrule[1pt]
                \If{$\sigma \in \Sigma_{\text{for}}$ \parbox[t]{.3\linewidth}{ $\vee (\forall \sigma^{'} \in \Sigma_{\omega\omega}^{i}) \sigma^{'} \in \Sigma_{c}$ \\ $\vee (\nexists \sigma^{'} \in \Sigma_{\omega\omega}^{i}) \text{pr}(\sigma^{'}, \sigma)$ \\ $\vee [(\Sigma_{\omega\omega}^{i} = \emptyset) \wedge (\sigma \in \Sigma_c)]$}}
                                \State \text{do something}
                \EndIf
            \Return z
        \end{algorithmic}
    \end{algorithm}

\end{document}
```

But the output has two main problems, as below:[image]

1- `then` must be placed in the last line of the condition (not the first one).

2- There is an unsual space between first condition and `then`.

How can I fix these issues, please?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why don't use some `\newline`s and `\hspace`s instead of a `\parbox` which in this case is difficult to manage?

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{mathptmx}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage{fdsymbol}
\usepackage{algorithm}
\usepackage{algorithmicx,algpseudocode}
\usepackage[top=2cm, left = 2cm, right = 2cm, bottom = 2cm]{geometry}

\algnewcommand\algorithmicforeach{\textbf{for each}}
\algdef{S}[FOR]{ForEach}[1]{\algorithmicforeach\ #1\ \algorithmicdo}

\algnewcommand\algorithmicinput{\textbf{Input:}}
\algnewcommand\INPUT{\item[\algorithmicinput]}

\algnewcommand\algorithmicoutput{\textbf{Output:}}
\algnewcommand\OUTPUT{\item[\algorithmicoutput]}

\let\oldReturn\Return
\renewcommand{\Return}{\State\oldReturn}

\makeatletter
\newcommand{\algrule}[1][.2pt]{\par\vskip.5\baselineskip\hrule height #1\par\vskip.5\baselineskip}
\makeatother

\begin{document}

        \begin{algorithm}[tbp]
        \caption{ttt}
        \begin{algorithmic}[1]
            \INPUT $x$
            \OUTPUT $y$
            \algrule[1pt]
                \If{$\sigma \in \Sigma_{\text{for}}$  $\vee (\forall \sigma^{'} \in \Sigma_{\omega\omega}^{i}) \sigma^{'} \in \Sigma_{c}$ \newline
                \hspace*{1.5cm} $\vee (\nexists \sigma^{'} \in \Sigma_{\omega\omega}^{i}) \text{pr}(\sigma^{'}, \sigma)$ \newline
                \hspace*{1.5cm} $\vee [(\Sigma_{\omega\omega}^{i} = \emptyset) \wedge (\sigma \in \Sigma_c)]$}
                                \State \text{do something}
                \EndIf
            \Return z
        \end{algorithmic}
    \end{algorithm}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Also I think that it should be better to write `\sigma'` instead of `\sigma^{'}` which looks ugly :-)